# Outlook 2010 Save .msg as Attachment Name

Tags: vba, outlook, save, email-attachments

I hope you can help me.  I am new to Outlook 2010 VBA, but need a macro to :-

Save a group of highlighted e-mails :-
   a) As .msg files;
   b) In a given folder;
   c) Where the name of each is the attachment name.

To give you an example, say there are 20 e-mails in my sent items folder, I want to highlight 10 of them and run this macro, winding-up with 10 flat files in a given folder which bear the name of the attachment for each e-mail.

Every e-mail subjected to this macro *will* have just one attachment, so to be crystal-clear, if we have an e-mail with a subject line "Random Text goes here doesn't matter what", and an attachment "GO.XLSX", I want the extracted file to be called GO.msg and, to confirm, this is Outlook 2010 I am running.

I have looked through loads of VBA sites and macro snippets, but I am getting nowhere =[

Comment: Currently I am just trying to get the VBA to *identify* the attachment's name to work, and am stuck with that - I have tried :-

Input1 = MsgBox(MailItem.Attachments.Item(1).DisplayName, vbOKOnly)

But it doesn't appear to work with run either on a selected file in a folder within Outlook, nor from within an e-mail itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem, but here is a quick example:

```
Sub QuickExample()
    For Each Item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Item.Attachments(1).DisplayName
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks so much for your help - I can't get that to work unfortunately.  Basically these e-mails will still be in my sent items folder, so I am trying to run a macro from within Outlook 2010 against a bunch of items in a folder, and have each item saved off as its attachment name, so if I have, say, three items and I drag each to my desktop, it will save as a flat file with the subject line as the filename.  I want to use this macro to save them off as flat files but where the filename is the *attachment* name (just the name, not its extension).  Thanks so much =]